# Loading an external properties file in sibling directory

Tags: java, maven, properties, classpath, maven-assembly-plugin

Following scenario

```
./
 config/
    application.properties
 lib/
    properties-loader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 acme.sh
```

`properties-loader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is an executable jar with a manifest file.
There is one package `com.acme.lab` within the jar, containing only the class 
with the fully qualified name `com.acme.lab.PropertiesLoader`.

The script `acme.sh` executes the following command:

```
java -cp etc/application.properties:./lib/properties-loader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.acme.lab.PropertiesLoader
```

I'm trying to access the properties file from the `PropertiesLoader` class. I read the article [Smartly load your properties](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html) but still have problems to access the properties file

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../etc/application.properties"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("etc/application.properties"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/etc/application.properties"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));

System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../etc/application.properties"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("etc/application.properties"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/etc/application.properties"));
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));

try {
    System.out.println(ResourceBundle.getBundle("etc.application"));
    System.out.println(ResourceBundle.getBundle("application"));
} catch(MissingResourceException e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

All these calls fail to load the file.

I just know that the error has something to do with the classpath, but can't seem to find it. I created a sample maven project on [github](https://github.com/oschrenk/properties-loader) that recreates the problem.

Comment: @drhirsch I think the tag `maven-assembly-plugin` tag may be more appropiate than `assemblies` in this context.

Comment: Of course, change it to what you find appropriate - but `assembly`, as it was before, was wrong. In fact, it was this tag, what brought me here - it's about machine code. Every tag has a description - read it in case you are unsure.

Comment: Forgot I could change it myself. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resources are interpreted from their classpath roots. Which in your case when you run your program like this:

```
java -cp etc/application.properties:./lib/properties-loader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The roots are

- `./etc/application.properties`
- `./lib/properties-loader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Neither of which contains your application.properties file (as a sub-resource). If you modified your command like this:

```
java -cp etc:./lib/properties-loader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then you could read your properties file in your program as:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
```

As a side note, its always best to use fully qualified paths in your classpath setting.

---

*** EDIT ***

This is a working example that should illustrate resource loading:

```
mkdir props; cd props
mkdir etc; touch etc/application.properties
mkdir test; vi test/PropLoader.java
```

Paste this content into the editor then save:

```
package test;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class PropLoader {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         final String path;
         if(args.length == 1) path = args[0].trim();
         else path = "etc/application.properties";

         final InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
         if(is == null) throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load " + path + " as a resource");
         else System.out.printf("Loaded resource from path: %s\n", path);
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

And to test:

```
javac test/PropLoader.java
java -cp . test.PropLoader
```

Output is `Loaded resource from path: etc/application.properties`.

Comment: Am I correct to understand thatthe classpath parameter should only contain paths and jars so that sub-resources can be loaded from there? Also I [tried](https://github.com/oschrenk/properties-loader/compare/stackoverflow) your solution but it still get `null` back as the InputStream.

Comment: Yes, your classpath should only contain `paths` and archives (jars). I edited my answer to include an example that should work if you follow precisely.

Comment: I can follow your example. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I still run into problems in production, the `ContextClassCloader` fails while `SystemClassLoader` works. Could it be that some component replaces the ClassLoader?